# How do I write a CRD using the kubernetes-client for javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, kubernetes, client

Examples are pretty limited, so going off what my IDE shows me and what I dig up from the source code. Having trouble.

I created my CRD already. I want to post it. Currently, its just a github webhook with a payload that I plan to trim later.  I can't seem to find the right constructor to pass to KubeConfig's makeApiClient function. I have the CRD, and I originally thought it was Custom_objectsApi, but that's only for the CRD creation and not a new Custom Object of my type.

Is there a way to do this? Do I have to make a new class myself? Can I just post raw yaml if that's the case?

Here is my CRD as well as the json I am trying to post.

```
  const yamlString = k8s.dumpYaml({
    "apiVersion": "hook-to-k8s.sfxworks.net/v1",
    "kind": "Payload",
    "metadata": {
      "type": "github",
      "name": event.payload.repository.name,
      "sha": event.payload.after,
      "head commit author": event.payload.head_commit.author.name
    },
    "spec": {
      "payload": event.payload
    }
  })
```

To clarify I am trying to post a object that has a kind using the CRD I created. Not  a new CRD.

For reference, using https://www.npmjs.com/package/@kubernetes/client-node

Answer (score 0):

If you've already built your CRD, you can access the objects in the kubernetes api like this.

```
const k8s = require('@kubernetes/client-node');

const kc = new k8s.KubeConfig()
kc.loadFromDefault();

const k8sClient = kc.makeApiClient(k8s.CustomObjectsApi);

resp = k8sClient.getNamespacedCustomObjectStatus('api.yourorg.io', apiVersion', namespace, crdKind, objName)
// resp.body is your object. for example resp.body.spec.
```

Comment: doesn't answer the question at all.

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible using the auto-generated methods:

- [CustomObjectsApi.createClusterCustomObject](https://kubernetes-client.github.io/javascript/classes/customobjectsapi.customobjectsapi-1.html#createclustercustomobject)
- [CustomObjectsApi.createNamespacedCustomObject](https://kubernetes-client.github.io/javascript/classes/customobjectsapi.customobjectsapi-1.html#createnamespacedcustomobject)

Usage example:

```js
import {
  CustomObjectsApi,
  KubeConfig
} from "@kubernetes/client-node";

// Split your example of hook-to-k8s.sfxworks.net/v1 into:
const group = "sfxworks.net";
const version = "v1";
const plural = "hook-to-k8s";

const kubeConfig = new KubeConfig();
kubeConfig.loadFromDefault();
const client = kubeConfig.makeApiClient(CustomObjectsApi);

const namespace = "foobar";
const body = { /* payload */ };

await client.createNamespacedCustomObject(
  group,
  version,
  namespace,
  plural,
  body
);
```